# Open external .swf in another frame or window

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to link to an external .swf file, which I have done, but it opens as a popup within the main .swf. What I want to do is either have it navigate to a blank frame with the external .swf there or have it open in a new window. How do I achieve this?

Here is the code I have which opens the external .swf:

```
private function openSWF():void {
        cSWFLoader = new Loader();
        cSWFPopup = addChild(cSWFLoader);
        cSWFLoader.x = cPopX;
        cSWFLoader.y = cPopY;

        try {
            cSWFLoader.load(new URLRequest(cSourceFile));
            cSWFLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, SWFLoaded);
        }catch (err:Error){
            trace("YOU DONE GOOFED", cSourceFile);
            trace("Error: ", err);
            cSourceFile = null;
        }
    }

private function SWFLoaded(evt:Event):void{
        cSWFLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragSWF);
        cSWFLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropSWF);
        cSWFPopup.content.gotoAndStop(cFrameLabel);
        cSWFPopup.content.closeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeSWF);
        cSWFLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, SWFLoaded);

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can make it with using [navigateToURL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()) or use [External interface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to use javascript for adding iframe

Comment: How would I use this? Do I use navigateToURL instead of load?

Comment: there is an example in that link for using navigateToURL... you have to use navigateURL instead of load because with load you are loading external swf to your main swf its not related with browser(opening in new tab iframe these are not in swf level). to manage browser you have to call javascript functions with ExternalInterface or you can use more simple as3 function (navigateToURL)

Comment: When you say you want to open a new window, are you talking about a new browser window ?